# Infix notation, stacks and queues

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on an assignment for my university class, we're required to write a script that evaluates a string of mathematical expressions that are bound by brackets (i.e '( ( (4 / 3) * 2) * 5)'). We're also required to use Stacks and Queues for this assignment which the professor provided us. I got my code to work, but its not giving me the proper output. Any insights to what I am doing wrong is helpful.

Here is my code written in Python 3:

```
import isfloat
import Queue
import Stack

def expr_eveluate(expr_string):
    """
    :Pre: Given a mathematical expression, this function
    evaluates it per pairs of brackets.
    :Post: The expression must be evaluated per pairs of brackets
    :param expr_string: A string of mathematical expressions
    :return:
    """
    #  A queue for data to be processed.
    waiting_line = Queue.create()
    #  A stack where processed operators go.
    operator_stack = Stack.create()
    #  A stack where processed numbers go.
    numerical_value = Stack.create()


    #  Put all the items in Queue
    expr = expr_string.split()
    for item in expr:
        Queue.enqueue(waiting_line, item)

    while not Queue.is_empty(waiting_line):
        item = Queue.dequeue(waiting_line)

        if item == '(':
            pass
        elif isfloat.isfloat(item):
            Stack.push(numerical_value, item)
        elif not isfloat.isfloat(item):
            Stack.push(operator_stack, item)
        else:
            num1 = Stack.pop(numerical_value)
            num2 = Stack.pop(numerical_value)
            op = Stack.pop(operator_stack)
            if op == '*':
                val = num1 * num2
                Stack.push(numerical_value, val)
            if op == '/':
                val = num1 / num2
                Stack.push(numerical_value, val)
            if op == '+':
                val = num1 + num2
                Stack.push(numerical_value, val)
            if op == '-':
                val = num1 - num2
                Stack.push(numerical_value, val)
            else:
                print("Syntax Error")
                return None

    return Stack.pop(numerical_value)
```

Comment: isfloat is another module provided by our professor. tries to convert character to float.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your title. Reverse polish notation has the operators after the arguments (e.g. `1 2 +`), but you're asking about normal notation with parentheses (e.g. `(1 + 2)`).

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm unfamiliar with the notation itself but my friend said it was either a RPN or a Postfix notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several issues with your code. Here's a rundown.

1. You're never converting your numbers to actual numeric types. You probably want to push `float(item)` to `numeric_stack` instead of just `item` in the `isfloat.isfloat(item)` case.
2. The conditions in your main `if`/`elif`/`else` chain are not consistent with each other. You could perhaps keep some of the same logic if you changed the order of the blocks around, but I think the current order is fine if you make the conditions better.

   In particular, in the line `elif not isfloat.isfloat(item):`, the condition will always be true (since you've already handled the numbers in the previous `elif` block). That means closing parentheses will be pushed onto the operator stack and the `else` block will never run. I think you should be explicitly testing for the expected operators here, with with something like `elif item in ("*", "/", "+", "-"):`.

   Similarly, the top level `else` block should probably be `elif item == ")"`, explicitly testing for the token it expects to handle.
3. The `if`s in your current `else` block should probably be a chain of `if` and `elif`s, since you only expect one of them to be run at a time. Currently the `else` clause at the end will run for any non `-` operator, not for an unknown operator value.

   Speaking of that inner `else` block, it should probably be unindented by one level so that it's part of the outer `if`/`elif` chain instead of the inner operator processing chain. You will want to to check for invalid tokens at the top level since the `operator_stack` will hopefully not be getting nonsense pushed to it any more.
4. When you pop two numbers off the `numeric_stack`, you're handling them in the wrong order. The first number that comes off the top of the stack is always going to be the value on the right side of the operator, while the second number popped will be the value on the left side. Currently you're interpreting `3 / 4` as `4 / 3`. This is easy to fix by simply swapping `num1` and `num2` in the lines where you make the `pop` calls. You might even want to consider renaming those variables something like `right` and `left` to make it even more clear how the operations will be done.
5. This one is not really an issue with your code, but with the example input you've shown. If you run your code on `'( ( (4 / 3) * 2) * 5)'`, it will not get processed correctly because of the tightly wrapped parentheses. You need to pass it `'( ( ( 4 / 3 ) * 2 ) * 5 )'` instead, so the `split` call you're using will correctly separate all of the tokens. I'd check the details of your assignment to see if you need to write a more sophisticated tokenizer or if you can just be more careful about the inputs you use for testing.